# Return Function Pointer in C++ Class

Tags: c++

This is the c ++ source I wrote. What I want to do is run init(), a member function of class A, and get_func returns the address of a function in a(), b(), c(), d(). Finally, func () is executed and I hope to see b. It seems very simple, but now this problem is bothering me.

The compiler gives me the following error:
- 'choice' was not declared in this scope
- 'a' was not declared in this scope
return a ();
- no matching function for call to 'A :: init (char)'
a.init ('b');

What am i missing?

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
private:
    int (A::*get_func())();
    int a(){printf("a");}
    int b(){printf("b");}
    int c(){printf("c");}
    int d(){printf("d");}

public:
    A();
    ~A();
    int init();
    char choice;
}

A::init(char ch) {
    this->choice = ch;
    int (A::*func)() = get_func();
    func();
}

int (A::*get_func())() {
    switch(choice) {
        case 'a' :
            return a;
        case 'b' :
            return b;
        case 'c' :
            return c;
        case 'd' :
            return d;
    }
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.init('b');
}
```

Comment: What is `get_func` supposed to return? What happens with e.g. `return a();`? What is *really* returned?

Comment: If `init` is for initialization only, it should be a c'tor. And if it's not, it needs a better name.

Comment: return a(); will call a() and the value returned from a is returned.

Comment: There are a large number of mistakes in this code, it would be better to start simpler, check it compiles, and then gradually add new things

Comment: I don't like to ask this kind of question, but have you considered using inheritance instead of this kind of architecture?

Comment: @Some programmer dude  I designed get_func returns function address to function pointer func.so Finally func() is called then print 'b'. but maybe.. function pointer syntax is wrong..

Comment: 김현우 I think you mean `pointer to a member function of A`

Comment: @Tom  thank you for answering. I thought of it as a very simple piece of code for learning c ++ syntax, but It's not working. So now I want to know the grammar without considering the development skills..

Comment: With C++11 I would recommend returning a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) so return some [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) type.

Comment: @김현우: C++ is a very difficult programming language. You need to spend many weeks learning it (not only its [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) but most importantly its [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science))...). I recommend reading [Stroustrup's *Programming in C++*](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) book, and also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) which introduces the right concepts..

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
class A {
private:
    int a(){printf("a");}
    int b(){printf("b");}
    int c(){printf("c");}
    int d(){printf("d");}

public:
    using func = int (A::*)();
    A();
    ~A();
    char choice;

private:
    func foo();

};

A::func A::foo() {
    switch(choice) {
        case 'a' :
            return &A::a;
        case 'b' :
            return &A::b;
        case 'c' :
            return &A::c;
        case 'd' :
            return &A::d;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning function pointer You were calling these functions instead.
Secondly, I would suggest using typedefs/using with member function types.
 Notice that You did not add semicolon at the end of class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your code, following compile:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
private:
    int (A::*get_func())();
    int a() {printf("a"); return 0;}
    int b() {printf("b"); return 0;}
    int c() {printf("c"); return 0;}
    int d() {printf("d"); return 0;}

public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    void init(char);
    char choice;
};

void A::init(char ch) {
    this->choice = ch;
    int (A::*func)() = get_func();
    (this->*func)(); // ->* or .* is use to call member function
}

int (A::*A::get_func())() // You forget one `A::`, so define a free function.
{
    switch(choice) {
        case 'a' :
            return &A::a; // &A:: is require for pointer on member
                          // due to compatibility with C
                          // & is not required for address of free function :/
        case 'b' :
            return &A::b;
        case 'c' :
            return &A::c;
        case 'd' :
            return &A::d;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.init('b');
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c14e9f5a98e185ee)

To avoid strange and ugly syntax, I suggest using typedef or trailling return type

```
auto get_func() -> int (A::*)();
```

and in out of class definition

```
auto A::get_func() -> int (A::*)();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try the inheritance-based approach:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    virtual int init(){ printf("a"); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    int init(){ printf("b"); }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C();
    ~C();
    int init(){ printf("c"); }
};

class D : public A {
public:
    D();
    ~D();
    int init(){ printf("d"); }
};
```

If you would like the base class (A) to be abstract:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    virtual int init() = 0;
};
```